# Errores ortográficos en "¿Que es "meta" y cómo funciona?"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, centro-de-ayuda

En la sección [¿Que es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) observo alguna falta ortográfica:

> ¿<strike>**Que**</strike> es "meta" y cómo funciona?

debería ser

> ¿**Qué** es "meta" y cómo funciona?

---

> Por favor <strike>**hecha**</strike> un vistazo para ver si tu
>   pregunta ya se ha realizado antes (...) <strike>**mas**</strike> bien,
>   es el lugar para mejorar nuestra comunidad y el sitio web, juntos.

debería ser

> Por favor **echa** un vistazo para ver si tu
>   pregunta ya se ha realizado antes (...) **más** bien,
>   es el lugar para mejorar nuestra comunidad y el sitio web, juntos.

---

> Haciendo preguntas sobre **como** funciona el sitio

debería ser

> Haciendo preguntas sobre **cómo** funciona el sitio

---

> sin embargo las medallas <strike>**si**</strike> están separadas

debería ser

> sin embargo las medallas **sí** están separadas

---

> [bug], denota un problema reproducible en el sitio que
>   <strike>**tu**</strike> crees que es un error, mal funcionamiento, o
>   error de programación.

debería ser

> [bug], denota un problema reproducible en el sitio que
>   **tú** crees que es un error, mal funcionamiento, o
>   error de programación.

Comment: oops creo que ese articulo lo traduje yo.. :$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Listo! Muchas gracias por la ayuda. :)

Comment: ¡A ti por la velocidad y la disposición!

Comment: Sigue habiendo errores especialmente de tildes: leg**í**timo, entre s**í**, m**ás** votos, p**á**ginas, el sitio en s**í**, utili**d**ad  (está escrito utilizad), en s**í**, publicar en **é**l, m**ú**ltiples, bu**g** (está escrito bub). Y puede que haya más, esas son las que he visto echándole un vistazo rápido.

Comment: Editado. :) Gracias por tu ayuda @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Para no abrir un nuevo tema @JuanM lo comento aquí. En el segundo punto: _Votar es diferente en Meta_, primer párrafo, primera línea: _Como en cualquier sitio en Stack Exchange, **Mete** permite..._, creo que debería ser _**Meta** permite..._

Comment: @OscarR. ¡Buen ojo! lo he editado. :)

Comment: Para no abrir un nuevo tema @JuanM lo comento aquí. En la página [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) en el punto: *¿Tienes el mismo problema?*  en el último enunciado: *Podrás también votar a favor la pregunta **o** ofrecer una recompensa...*, creo que debería ser *Podrás también votar a favor la pregunta **u** ofrecer una recompensa...*

Comment: @AngelOropeza Excelente observación.  Lo he corregido. :)