# Desambiguación de etiquetas [documentación] y [centro de ayuda]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, meta, desambiguación-etiquetas

[centro-de-ayuda](/questions/tagged/centro-de-ayuda) y [documentación](/questions/tagged/documentaci%c3%b3n) no tienen wiki de etiqueta y ambas tienen pocas preguntas, la primera tiene 9 y la segunda tiene 5.

He visto que ambas se usan en preguntas sobre artículos de ayuda pero documentación se ha usado para otros temas.

Las siguientes tenían sólo [documentación](/questions/tagged/documentaci%c3%b3n) y recién les agregué [centro-de-ayuda](/questions/tagged/centro-de-ayuda)

- [Cambiar tilde y enlace en "Como aceptar una respuesta" de la sección de ayuda "¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1526/65)
- [Errores ortográficos en "¿Que es "meta" y cómo funciona?"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/575/65)

Algunas dudas

- ¿Es correcto que tengan ambas, deberíamos hacer una sinónimo de la otra?
- Si es correcto que tengan ambas para que más deberíamos usar [documentación](/questions/tagged/documentaci%c3%b3n)
- Si no es correcto que tengan ambas ni deberíamos hacer sinónimo una de la otra ¿eliminamos documentación?

En síntesis, ¿Qué hacemos con  estas etiquetas?

---

A partir las propuestas mencionadas en los comentarios se han agregado algunas alternativas para ser votadas.

Comment: Mi punto de vista personal sería definir mejor su alcance, porque creo que las dos podrían tener cabida sin eliminar ninguna de las dos (aunque veo como la línea entre ellas es a veces borrosa). Puede haber preguntas que son de documentación pero que no tengan que ver con el centro de ayuda (por ejemplo traducciones del blog/preguntas interesantes de metaSE), limitando la etiqueta de [tag:centro-de-ayuda] a preguntas específicas sobre artículos que se encuentran en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Cuando dices que puede haber preguntas de documentación te refieres a la directamente relacionada en específico con [es.so] y en general con [se] sin incluir los alcances del difunto "Documentation" de SO ¿verdad?

Comment: Sí, correcto. Esa "Documentación" es como ese familiar del que nadie quiere hablar :P

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro jajaja no lo decía por eso sino porque hay hilos que hablan sobre el equivalente a hacer un manual en español de un lenguaje, api, herramienta de terceros, etc.

Comment: Yo me cargaría [meta-tag:documentación]. Se creó para [una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/932/83) que hablaba de documentación e idiomas, donde creo que no era necesaria; luego la usé yo en alguna otra sin mayor pensamiento. Visto que tenemos [meta-tag:centro-de-ayuda] y para eso se está usando últimamente, propongo dejar esta última y ya.

Comment: @Rubén sugiero que hagas esta pregunta de tipo encuesta, con eso ya sabremos puntualmente qué es lo que decide la comunidad y no quedaría solo en comentarios ;)

Comment: @Flxtr: Listo. Si alguien tiene otra alternativa favor de agregarla como respuesta para que sea votada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternativa 2

Usar [centro-de-ayuda](/questions/tagged/centro-de-ayuda) para preguntas sobre el centro de ayuda de SOes.

Retirar [documentación](/questions/tagged/documentaci%c3%b3n) de las preguntas que traten sobre documentación de SOes y SE. Si quedara alguna pregunta que justificara su uso ya se analizaría en lo particular, es decir, por lo pronto <kbd>N</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> se agregará esta etiqueta a la lista negra.

Comment: He retirado [meta-tag:documentación] de las preguntas en Meta que la tenían.

Comment: ¡Gracias por hacerlo, Rubén!

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa 1

Usar [documentación](/questions/tagged/documentaci%c3%b3n) para preguntas sobre cualquier documentación de SOes en particular y SE en general pero no para preguntas sobre documentación de lenguajes, APIs, herramientas, etc. externos.

Usar [centro-de-ayuda](/questions/tagged/centro-de-ayuda) para preguntas sobre el centro de ayuda de SOes

La primera es más general y la segunda es específica por lo que ambas podrías usarse en preguntas sobre artículos de ayuda de SOes.